# How to cache async module response

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, command-line-interface

I have a module I'm loading via require, which returns an emitter, so when the async functions within the module are done (load, parse and process several json files), emits an event I can use on the requiring script.

The requiring script:

```
LoadJson = require('./loadjsonfiles');
...
LoadJson.loadJsonFiles()
  .on('data', function(result) {
      jsonTags = result;
      checkTags();
  });
```

The module returns:

```
return emitter;
```

When all async load and processes are done

```
emitter.emit('data', jsonTags);
```

This is working perfectly, with an emitter, and returning the expected values, but the requirement is that I should be caching that so a second call to this module would just return the cached value instead of going through all the async steps within the loaded module ..

By the way, this is fired from the CLI, so no server available, and one of the requirements is not to use but core modules ..

So how do I cache the response?
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function scope to store/cache the result:

```
var getJson = (function(){
  var data = null;

  return function(cb) {
    if data
      cb(data);
    else 
      LoadJson = require('./loadjsonfiles');
      LoadJson.loadJsonFiles()
        .on('data', function(result) {
            data = result;
            cb(data);
        });
  }

}());

// loads the json
getJson(function(data) {


  // later: uses the cached result
  getJson(function(data) {

  });

});
```

Comment: Nice approach, but maybe my fault. The script should be called from the CLI with params, and I want the data to cache so if the script is called from the CLI a second time, it would already have all the process cached (the json files loaded would not be changed in between)

Comment: Ahh okay sorry,
In this case you must write the result to a file in order to cache it..